# CSS: how can I make boxes of different height and same width perfectly arrange in div in such a way that box6 will under box1

Tags: css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.floating-box {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;  
}

.f-box {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;  
}
.after-box {
    clear: left;
    border: 3px solid red;      
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>The Old Way - using float</h2>

<div class="f-box">Floating box1</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box2</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box3</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box4</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box5</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box6</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box7</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box8</div>

<div class="after-box">Another box, after the floating boxes...</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS: how can I make boxes of different height and same width perfectly arrange in div in such a way that box6 will under box1 and all boxes that is the same column as box6 will follow its top position. Something that looks like this

[image]

Comment: Add <div class="clearfix"></div> after box5?

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss and the relevant css for that class is?

Comment: @user3714598 Please have a look on my answer, If you feel I gave you correct solution. Please mark as answer or please provide me any feedback , If i didn't go it right. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap all the `floating-box` inside a div which has `display:flex;` and then use `flex-wrap:wrap;` property.

You can make their width in percentage `width:15%;` or like that so that only a fix number of div are in a row at any screen size.

```css
.floating-box {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;  
}
.f-container{
  display:flex;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.f-box {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;  
}
.after-box {
    clear: left;
    border: 3px solid red;      
}
```

```html
<h2>The Old Way - using float</h2>

<div class="f-container">
<div class="f-box">Floating box1</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box2</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box3</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box4</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box5</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box6</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box7</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box8</div>
</div>

<div class="after-box">Another box, after the floating boxes...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an empty `div` with style `clear:both`. we call this a `clearfix` which comes handy while using `float`.

Read more about [clearfix](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

```css
.container{
 width: 900px;
}
.clearfix{
 clear: both;
}
.floating-box {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;  
}

.f-box {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;  
}
.after-box {
    clear: left;
    border: 3px solid red;      
}
```

```html
<h2>The Old Way - using float</h2>
<div class="container">
<div class="f-box">Floating box1</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box2</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box3</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box4</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box5</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box6</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box7</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box8</div>

<div class="after-box">Another box, after the floating boxes...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If , I understand you correctly then you want every box break after 5th and comes under 1 box as many boxes you like to add.**

**HTML :**

```
<h2>The Old Way - using float</h2>



<div class="parent-box"> 
<div class="floating-box">Floating box1</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box2</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box3</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box4</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box5</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box6</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box7</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box8</div>

</div>
<div class="after-box">Another box, after the floating boxes...</div>
```

i have added a **parent Div**

**CSS:**

```
.parent-box .floating-box:nth-child(5n+1){
  clear: left;

}
.floating-box {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;  
}

.f-box {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;  
}
.after-box {
    clear: left;
    border: 3px solid red;      
}
```

I have used **nth-child method**

[**Here JS Fiddle for it.**](https://jsfiddle.net/wikijames/2rs23umb/)

Answer (score 0):

One more way to resolve it using pure CSS, is wrapping every box into `div` with constant height.

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
[class*='box'] {
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;  
}
.floating-box { 
    height: 75px;
}
.floating-box4 { 
    height: 95px;
}
.floating-box7 { 
    height: 25px;
}
.f-box {
    height: 90px;
}
.after-box {
    clear: left;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h2>The Old Way - using float</h2>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="f-box">Floating box1</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box2</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box3</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="floating-box4">Floating box4</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box5</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box6</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="floating-box7">Floating box7</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box8</div>
</div>
<div class="after-box">Another box, after the floating boxes...</div>
```